# What is the iPhone Search Bar Height (minimum possible)?

Tags: height, titanium, uisearchbar, minimum-size

Been trying to find the height of the iPhone Search Bar but all I found on google were pages talking about iphone tab bars, and also happened to have a (webpage, not iphone) search bar that says "search".

Does anyone know what the size of the rounded text field of the search bar is?

I want to set the search bar height to its very minimum.

On a sidenote, I want to hide the sides around the bar if possible but I doubt its possible right?

Answer (score 0):

I would be very careful editing IOS's core features, this could lead to your app being rejected from the app store.